# In silanization, how to clean kerosene from glass surface completely?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, surface-chemistry

I'm doing some silanization experiments using kerosene to dilute the silan solution. For instance I use a mixture of 10% silan in kerosene. However, after several tests I realized that I cannot completely clean the surface from the remaining kerosene after silanization, and in fact the contact angle that I read is more related to kerosene rather than silan. After silanization, I wash the glass surface with a stream of water and then put the surface in a bottle of acetone and then shake the bottle for 20 sec to clean the kerosene, but apparently it is not enough.
What is the most effective way to get rid of the remaining kerosene on the glass surface?

Comment: The best way would be to use some other anhydrous solvent rather than kerosene which is an organic goo from a chemist's point of view.

Comment: How about a low-boiling solvent such as pure  hexane, which could be baked off?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't have hexane in the lab, but you think Acetone is not enough to clean the kerosene?

Comment: @MaxW From this problem, that kerosene cannot easily be removed from glass surface, I'm wondering whether it's possible for me to use a kerosene coating for my glass particles (which gives me a contact angle~45 instead of silanization)? I want to shoot each glass particle by a particle launcher. So, my particles are not too much in contact with water so that the kerosene could be removed. Do you think it works?

Comment: I'm baffled as to why you'd want some sort of atomic layer coating on a glass projectile.

Comment: @MaxW I'm doing an investigation on collision of a particle and a droplet and now I need to consider the effect of particle wettability on collision outcome. My particles are very small (d=2mm) and that's why I've chosen glass because I think that I can create different wettabilities on its surface. I appreciate if let me know in case you have any better idea.

Comment: What is the velocity of the collision?

Comment: @MaxW Please see [this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42828/what-is-the-best-material-for-my-particles)